# How to get xpath for the search option in table column

Tags: selenium, xpath

[image]

I'm trying to get the Xpath for the search in table column.  All the search option in all the table columns are having the same class name, tabindex and role.

Answer (score 0):

Try below xpath:

```
//span[text()='Claim No.']/following-sibling::span//span[@role='button']
```